# Django Pagination Errors Caused by Googlebot 2.1

Tags: python, django, googlebot

In last few days, Googlebot 2.1 start hitting one of my sites with random invalid pagination values such as `/search/?page=nqfyvdhlopvyn` that are returning page errors.

**Django error info received by email**

```
page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nqfyvdhlopvyn'
...
<WSGIRequest
path:/search/,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'page': [u'nqfyvdhlopvyn']}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
...
'REQUEST_URI': '/search/?page=nqfyvdhlopvyn',
```

**The view causing the errors:**

```
try:
    page = paginator.page(int(request.GET.get('page', 1)))
except InvalidPage:
    raise Http404("No such page of results!")
```

I'm not sure where is google coming from with those search terms and also I'm surprised Django is returning an error since the `try:` should avoid those types of errors?

Comment: I'm not sure where that strange url is coming from, but why not use pagination's `PageNotAnInteger` exception to redirect to page 1?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the pagination based on your suggestion and Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view. It seems to be working OK now. Thank again!

Comment: You bet! Hopefully googlebot will stop making such strange requests...

Comment: I wish Google would stop with that nonsense. I have 100s of invalid URL `Crawl Errors` through the webmaster tools with showing no `Linked From` info. Just a bunch of invalid links that I cant even track. Very frustrating.

Comment: It might be worth cross-referencing those urls with Google Analytics, and if you still can't find any more information on them consider adding 301 redirects to your .htaccess. I'd also try doing a site search for your domain (go to google and search `site:yourdomain.com`) to see if you notice anything interesting

Comment: I may do that, thanks for the suggestion!